# redirect 301 multiple domain name haproxy

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I have a lot of domain names (example.com, www.example.com, example.net, www.example.net, etc...).

How can I redirect all these domains with haproxy ?

For the moment, I am able to redirect domain name by domain name with :

```
redirect prefix http://www.example.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i example.fr }
redirect prefix http://www.example.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i www.example.fr }
```

But I'd like to have just one line with all my domain names...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try an if statement that checks if the host is not www.example.com

```
redirect prefix http://www.example.com code 301 if !{ hdr(host) -i www.example.com }
```